# Styling HTML Select

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to style the HTML Select attribute to be more flat looking? I can set the border to be 1px solid but the dropdown portion still looks 3D and ugly looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript) for some other options using JavaScript and what you can style using CSS.

Comment: I swear I have seen some sites do this. Are there any alternatives? Like a UI plugin that is just made to look like a select box?

Comment: They're mocking up a dropdown using css and javascript, not actually manipulating a `<select>` tag. Here's one example: http://www.brainfault.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-selectbox-replacement/

Comment: Thanks! I kind of figured that's what they were doing...but I couldn't think of any examples off the top of my head.