# Can I use HTML tags in the options for select elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible for the options of an HTML select element to include HTML tags?

For example, given the following code:

```
 <select>
    <option value="one"><b>one is bold</b></option>
    <option value="two">two has some <span style='color:red;'>red</span> text</option>
    <option value="three">three is just normal</option>
 </select>
```

I would like the options to actually render in HTML.  In this application I can play with HTML, CSS, JavaScript (including jQuery).  And the HTML itself is being rendered via Django (django.form.fields.select).

Comment: No..is invalid html...asking for big problems from IE

Comment: Wow, I thought it would be possible, but no! To do this I suppose you would need to use some JavaScript that emulates (or converts, so that the select is still there when JS is not) a select box without actually being one. I'm confident you could find someone who has already made such a thing.

Comment: @charlietfl—re `big problems from IE`. Such as? Why single out IE to misbehave when given invalid HTML? It just ignores *b* tags in an option element.

Comment: @RobG only singled out IE since it doesn't support events on option tag, or `display:none` and is definitely more touchy than other browsers with invalid html - certainly with ajax. In this case- I honestly didn't try it and assumed it would cause issues, but am sure about the text only nodes allowed in tag... did you test back to IE6&7?

Comment: Use a javascript widget, like jQuery UI's selectMenu, if you want complete control and really need your markup to be a <select>. Or, look for a javascript widget that can handle a <ul> list or javascript data, like JQWidgets jqxDropDownList.

Comment: Try it like this.    <option value="&lt; style='color:rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color:rgb(255, 235, 0);border-radius:10px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;'>하고 싶은 말&lt;/b&gt;
">&lt;/html&gt;쓰고 싶은 말&lt;/html&gt;</option>    &lt; = <   /  &gt; = >

Answer (score 103, accepted):

No, you can't do this. `<option>` tags cannot contain any other tags.

Comment: In Chrome at least, <option> tags can contain <script> tags. They will behave like normal <script> tags, meaning they will not be visible, but they will execute. This is causing me some consternation at the moment.

Comment: @SamKauffman That's illegal markup. Just because Chrome will try to muddle through it doesn't mean "<option> tags can contain <script> tags". You cannot rely on this behavior.

Comment: Actually I was trying to prevent that behavior, which is a potential injection attack vector. It turned out to require nothing more than simple server-side HTML escaping. I was confused before because I didn't realize that what Chrome shows you in the Elements view is _after_ substituting HTML entities.

Answer (score 7):

No, but this: [Styling HTML Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418280/styling-html-select) may help you and there a lof of detail and votes here:

[How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Comment: It's not particularly helpful to link to another question that was closed as a duplicate and has no meaningful answers.

Comment: Try it like this. <option value="&lt; style='color:rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color:rgb(255, 235, 0);border-radius:10px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;'>하고 싶은 말&lt;/b&gt; ">&lt;/html&gt;쓰고 싶은 말&lt;/html&gt;</option> &lt; = < / &gt; = >

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot.

What you would do if you wanted this is use something like a floating div and position and display it using Css to look like a select. Then using javascipt clicks allow users to select.

Something like this: [Reinventing the dropdown](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx)

Comment: Note that reinventing the drop down is a really, really bad idea. The select is incredibly simple and has a ton of semantic meaning. Cobbling together DOM elements with JavaScript to *visually* approximate the same thing will be massively inaccessible.

Comment: Agreed. Keyboard accessibility that select boxes provide make for a good UI. But this is what the question poster is trying to achieve.

Comment: The attached field is not found

Comment: Try it like this. <option value="&lt; style='color:rgb(0, 0, 0);background-color:rgb(255, 235, 0);border-radius:10px;padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;'>하고 싶은 말&lt;/b&gt; ">&lt;/html&gt;쓰고 싶은 말&lt;/html&gt;</option> &lt; = < / &gt; = >

Answer (score 2):

option tag does not allow any children other than text

Here is a fiddle I created a few months ago that replaces a select element with a list dropdown, and updates the select for each selection made.  Just hide select with css
http://jsfiddle.net/6zcRk/

The user in this thread then turned it into a plugin available on github( see link in thread)

[Custom drop-down panel with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548618/custom-drop-down-panel-with-jquery)