# getting the id inside a <span> inside a <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have the following code :-

```
<div class="DropDownContainer">
    <select class="DropDown">
        <option><span id="lblPeriod">Period</span></option>
        <option><span id="lblLike">Like</span></option>
        <option><span id="lblYear">Year</span> </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to get the id of the selected value, and I have the following jquery :-

```
        $('.DropDown').on('change', function () {

           var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("span.id");
           alert(id);
        });
```

However id is undefined.  $(this).val() will return the text, for example "Period", "Like" or "Year", however I need the id, since this is a multilang project, so I have to depend on the id.

What is wrong with my jquery?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: What happens when you put the id at the option element and not in a span inside the option element? (get rid of the extra span)?

Comment: Option tags cannot have child elements which is why this won't work properly

Comment: To support pete's commment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements

Comment: "`[option] Permitted content Text with eventually escaped characters (like &eacute;).`" Citated from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option element cant have span inside it:

Change your html to:

```
<select class="DropDown">
    <option id="period">Period</option>
    <option id="like">Like</option>
    <option id="year">Year </option>
</select>


$('.DropDown').on('change', function () {
   var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
   alert(id);
});
```

If Multilanguage is your issue in Asp.net, you can have resource key for option elements too, like:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="MyDdl" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Value="period" Text="period" meta:resourcekey ="period_Item_MyDdl" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="like" Text="like" meta:resourcekey ="like_Item_MyDdl" />
   <asp:ListItem Value="year" Text="year" meta:resourcekey ="year_Item_MyDdl" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: its still returning undefined!

Comment: This is code generated by the page, because I am using an <asp:label> since I need multilanguage to work

Comment: I did as you suggested Akhil, and I am getting the value now like this $(this).val() however I am not getting the selected value

Comment: did you mean the selected option id

Comment: Yes basically now I need the Value, however $(this).val() is not returning period, or like or year

Comment: can you create a JSBin so that we can discuss

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33894/discussion-between-johann-and-akhil-sekharan)

Answer (score 2):

It works using

```
<div class="DropDownContainer">
    <select class="DropDown">
        <option id="lblPeriod">Period</option>
        <option id="lblLike">Like</option>
        <option id="lblYear">Year</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and

```
$('.DropDown').on('change', function () {
  var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
  alert(id);
});
```

You set the ID on the option element. Also, you'll have to set a `value` attribute on tne option for it to work as a submittable form.

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YdXpv/1/

Comment: till_b ideally I would do it like that, however the code I have is generated, since I am using the <asp:label> because I need to use a multilang site

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
 $('.DropDown').on('change', function () {

      var id = $(this).children(":selected").text().find("span").prop("id");
      alert(id);
 });
```

Comment: @Johann try by removing the option.

Answer (score 0):

use `find()` and `prop()`

```
 var id = $(this).children(":selected").find('span').prop("id");
```