# angular.js ng-repeat li items with html content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a model that comes back from the server which contains html instead of text (for instance a b tag or an i tag) 
when I use ng-repeat to built a list out of it it shows the html as pure text, is there a built in filter or directive that put's the html inside the li items or not? 
I've looked in the documentation but since I'm still very new to it I'm having difficulties finding it.

ng-repeat:

```
    <li ng-repeat="opt in opts">
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gFFBa/1/

Comment: In your jsFiddle you're trying to put html in `option` tags. You can not do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements

Comment: I've included the wrong fiddle, my bad now it's the correct one

Comment: ok , have a look at my answer

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It goes like `ng-bind-html-unsafe="opt.text"`:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat=" opt in opts" ng-bind-html-unsafe="opt.text" >
        {{ opt.text }}
    </li>
    </ul>

    <p>{{opt}}</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gFFBa/3/

Or you can define a function in scope:

```
 $scope.getContent = function(obj){
     return obj.value + " " + obj.text;
 }
```

And use it this way:

```
<li ng-repeat=" opt in opts" ng-bind-html-unsafe="getContent(opt)" >
     {{ opt.value }}
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gFFBa/4/

Note that you can not do it with an `option` tag: [Can I use HTML tags in the options for select elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements)

Comment: how do you seperate properties in the expression, I thought through a comma seperated list or array ([]) but it only shows the first one then.
for instance ng-bind-html-unsafe="opt.text, opt.value"

Comment: does this still work in angular 1.2? i noticed that the fiddles are using 1.0

Comment: html-bind-unsafe has being removed since 1.2 @see [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngbindhtmlunsafe-has-been-removed-and-replaced-by-ngbindhtml)

Answer (score 11):

Note that ng-bind-html-unsafe is no longer suppported in rc 1.2. Use ng-bind-html instead. See: [With ng-bind-html-unsafe removed, how do I inject HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html)

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up since pretty much everything else here is deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [NGBindHTML](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml) or [NGbindHtmlUnsafe](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe) this will not escape the `html` content of your model.

http://jsfiddle.net/n9rQr/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat=" opt in opts"  ng-bind-html-unsafe="opt.text">
        {{ opt.text }}
    </li>
    </ul>

    <p>{{opt}}</p>
</div>
```

This works, anyway you should be very careful when using `unsanitized` `html` content, you should *really trust* the source of the content.

Answer (score 4):

use `ng-bind-html-unsafe`

it will apply html with text inside like below:

```
    <li ng-repeat=" opt in opts" ng-bind-html-unsafe="opt.text" >
        {{ opt.text }}
    </li>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is directive from the official examples [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) v1.5 that shows how to compile html:

```
.directive('compileHtml', function ($compile) {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
      function(scope) {
        return scope.$eval(attrs.compileHtml);
      },
      function(value) {
        element.html(value);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
    );
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
<div compile-html="item.htmlString"></div>
```

It will insert item.htmlString property as html any place, like

```
<li ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    <div compile-html="item.htmlString"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want some element to contain a value that is HTML, take a look at [ngBindHtmlUnsafe](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe).

If you want to style options in a *native* select, no it is not possible.

Comment: I'm sorry I've forgot to update the fiddle, my bad if you'd look now you'll see what I was trying to accomplish

Comment: and how you're using it with a `ng-repeat` directive?

Answer (score 1):

ng-bind-html-unsafe is deprecated from 1.2. The correct answer should be currently:

HTML-side: (the same as the accepted answer stated):

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat=" opt in opts" ng-bind-html-unsafe="opt.text">
        {{ opt.text }}
      </li>
   </ul>

   <p>{{opt}}</p>
</div>
```

But in the controller-side:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
// ...
   $scope.opts.map(function(opt) { 
      opt = $sce.trustAsHtml(opt);
   });
}
```

Comment: You should use ` ng-bind-html` if you call `$sce.trustAsHtml`