# Angular ngRepeat html content

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs

I have the following:

```
<div class="columns large-12">
    <p ng-repeat="desc in joinUs.description">{{desc}}</p>
</div>
```

How can I display html content inside the repeated paragraph? Basically I want to repeat:

```
<p ng-bind-html="{{desc}}"></p>
```

joinUs.description is an array of strings, some containing anchor tags.

Edit

I have tried this the following (as suggested [angular.js ng-repeat li items with html content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111337/angular-js-ng-repeat-li-items-with-html-content)) but the html is still shown as plain text.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns large-12">
        <p ng-repeat="desc in joinUs.description" ng-bind-html-unsafe="desc">{{desc}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use a directive instead, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417607/angular-ng-bind-html-unsafe-and-directive-within-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 <p ng-repeat="desc in joinUs.description" ng-bind-html="desc"></p>
```

plunkr with similar use is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/wiHj5kwdbb08ag8NQcoJ?p=preview

(it might help, if you add a working sample as plunkr/fiddle or similar)

edit:

ng-bind-html-unsafe has been deprecated. see this stackoverflow question: [With ng-bind-html-unsafe removed, how do I inject HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415394/with-ng-bind-html-unsafe-removed-how-do-i-inject-html)

Comment: Working, thanks. I did not include the sanitize script, hence it did not work initially.