# image won't display at my page via function in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to display images in text instead of :) symbols.
I have an html + angularjs 14.8. page with code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="message in messages | filter:searchForMessage" my-directive="message">
    <td align="left" ng-class='{sent :message.id_user_sent == hiddenFriendId, recieved: message.id_user_sent != hiddenFriendId}'>
            {{message.id_user_sent == hiddenFriendId ? "&#x21FD" : "&#x21D2"}} {{emoji(message.message)}}
    </td>
```

and I got a function emoji to convert :) to image:

```
$scope.emoji = function(text) {
var getUrlToMessages = "http://"+location.hostname+(location.port ? ':'+location.port: '')+"/";
var emoticons = {
        ':)'  : getUrlToMessages +'img_smile.png',
        ':('  : getUrlToMessages +'img_sad.png',
        ':D'  : getUrlToMessages +'img_haha.png',
        ':o'  : getUrlToMessages +'img_omg.png'
      }, patterns = [], metachars = /[[\]{}()*+?.\\|^$\-,&#\s]/g;
  // build a regex pattern for each defined property
  for (var i in emoticons) {
      if (emoticons.hasOwnProperty(i)){ // escape metacharacters
          patterns.push('('+i.replace(metachars, "\\$&")+')');
      }
  }
  // build the regular expression and replace
  return text.replace(new RegExp(patterns.join('|'),'g'), function (match) {
      return typeof emoticons[match] != 'undefined' ?'<img ng-src="'+emoticons[match]+'"/>' : match;
  });
}
```

the problem is that I have no image as an output in my UI - I got a text only:

> <img
>   src="http://192.168.169.1:8182/ChatGUINoSQL/messages/img_smile.png"/>

which looks like a proper tag at UI, but this is a text only (cause it changes < and > symbols to the code).

What should I do to see images instead of this URL text?
Thank you!

**Fix**

Add:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

Update html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="message in messages | filter:searchForMessage">
    <td align="left" ng-class='{sent :message.id_user_sent == hiddenFriendId, recieved: message.id_user_sent != hiddenFriendId}'>
    {{message.id_user_sent == hiddenFriendId ? "&#x21FD" : "&#x21D2"}} <div ng-bind-html="emoji(message.message)"></div> <!-- {{ message.message }}  -->
    </td>
```

js updated:

```
// build the regular expression and replace
  return text.replace(new RegExp(patterns.join('|'), 'g'), function (match) {
    var escape = typeof emoticons[match] != 'undefined' ? '<img src="' + emoticons[match] + '" />' : match;
    return  $sce.trustAsHtml(escape);
  });
```

Comment: It's probably the `img` your returning. This might help.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25513186/1339516

Comment: @Searching thanks, but it looks like I got a different version or this solution is not compatible to my situation. Anyway, thank you, I made an update

Comment: Just in case - this one looks useful, but not working in my solution.. Don't know why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111337/angular-js-ng-repeat-li-items-with-html-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ngSanitize`  [cdn](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.min.js) to your app.

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])// your app
```

inject in controller

```
 myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$sce) { // your controller
```

update return statement. Lets mark the html safe to display. [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

```
return text.replace(new RegExp(patterns.join('|'), 'g'), function (match) {
    var escape = typeof emoticons[match] != 'undefined' ? '<img src="' + emoticons[match] + '" />' : match;
    return  $sce.trustAsHtml(escape);
});
```

update html

```
<div ng-bind-html="emoji(message.message)"></div>
```

Let us know if it's still causing issue.

Comment: You have a small typo with extra ) , but the problem is that I got an error: Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error

Comment: may be I made something wrong here: `(function () {
    'use strict';
angular.module('myAppName', ['ngResource']).controller('ContactController', ['$scope', '$sce', '$http', '$interval', function($scope, $sce, $http, $interval) {`
  ?

Comment: sorry that was a extra ) in the `var escape =` . Did you link to the cdn you will need to load https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular-resource.min.js script or from you local. You will need ngResource. @AlekseyKiselev Your declaration looks good.

Comment: thank you, I have no errors any more, but no I have nothing in output. Here is my code: `<tr ng-repeat="message in messages | filter:searchForMessage">
         <td align="left" ng-class='{sent :message.id_user_sent == hiddenFriendId, recieved: message.id_user_sent != hiddenFriendId}'>
          {{message.id_user_sent == hiddenFriendId ? "&#x21FD" : "&#x21D2"}} <div ng-bind-html="emoji(message.message)"></div> <!-- {{ message.message }}  -->
         </td>`

Comment: @AlekseyKiselev Can you inspect the element to see if the `img` tag has been added correctly ? Update this code bit in the question. kinda hard to read...

Comment: @AlekseyKiselev So the `img` tag wasn't on the page ?

Comment: I put my updated code with EDIT 2 header. Answer on your question - Nope, it throws an error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/unsafe

Comment: @AlekseyKiselev just saw you are using 1.4.8, so make sure ngResource is also 1.4.8 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-resource.min.js instead of 1.5.9.

Comment: Base on debug - escape = "<img src="http://192.168.169.1:8182/ChatGUINoSQL/messages/img_smile.png" />" when text = :). But I still got an error https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/unsafe

Comment: Boom! Fixed! Just added `<script src="angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>` and made an updated for module: `angular.module('myAppName', ['ngResource','ngSanitize']).` @Searching, Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @AlekseyKiselev Oh I thought it was a part of `ngResource`. Sorry about that man..

Comment: oh, not a problem :) You really helped me, issue resolved and that's the main thing