# Angular ng-if inside option element and ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have select element which should list available currencies. Default currency should have prefix "Default" before its name. For some reason, that prefix is showing for all currencies in the list.

Test HTML:

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <select>
        <option ng-repeat="rate in rates track by $index">
            <span ng-if="rate.is_default">Default</span>
            <span>{{rate.name}}</span>
        </option>
     </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

TEST JS:

```
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){

$scope.rates = [
    { 'name': 'dolar', 'is_default': true},
    { 'name': 'pound', 'is_default': false},
    { 'name': 'euro', 'is_default': false}
];

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nenadpavlov/sUP7G/1/)

Comment: [Can I use HTML tags in the options for select elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements) Your problem has nothing to do with angularjs. `<option>` tags cannot contain any other tags.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense then... Thanks for heads up. :/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't use HTML tags in an option tag but you can do something like this:

```
<option ng-repeat="rate in rates track by $index">
    {{ rate.is_default ? 'default' : '' }} {{rate.name}}
</option>
```

### Fiddle

Comment: isit possible to have a dynamic name instead of 'default'  like {{rate.name}} ?

Comment: Yes that's possible, it's an angular expression as any others. So you could use `{{ rate.is_default ? rate.name : '' }}`