# AngularJS Options in a Select based on a condition

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a `<select>` element, which will possibly have a default `<option>` set based on a condition - that condition being if another user has previously submitted the form and created the object being submitted. However, it seems I can't apply `ng-if` to an Option element (or any tags) and I'm finding it hard to come up with a solution.

Currently, my code looks like:

```
<select
    id="someId"
    ng-options="(item?'Yes':'No') for item in [true, false]"
    class="someClass"
    ng-class="someMethodToGetDynamicClass('this')
    ng-model="myObject.thisOption"
    ng-disabled="valueCheckingIfThisObjectHasBeenPreviouslySubmitted">
    <option ng-if="valueCheckingIfThisObjectHasBeenPreviouslySubmitted" selected>{{myObject.thisOption}}</option>
</select>
```

The selected option should only be set if `valueCheckingIfThisObjectHasBeenPreviouslySubmitted` is true - this means someone else has submitted the form before, and so the value has been set and should only be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a filter or, easier option, avoid `ng-options` attribute on `<select>` and use instead `ng-repeat` on `<option>` element

I simplify your code to provide a fast example (and even because I can't see the cycle part... You simplified it and something went lost? Or maybe it's just friday afternoon and I can't see it :)

```
<select ng-options="item for item in items" ng-model="selectedItem">
</select>
```

This would become

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem">
    <option ng-repeat="item for item in items" ng-if="item === yourConditionVariableOrElse">{{item}}<option>
</select>
```

I hope the procedure it's clear even with the simplifications.

Comment: From what I've read, `ng-if` can't be used on an `<option>` tag - am I mistaken?

Comment: indeed you can use it ;) I corrected the mistake, `ng-repeat` in place of `ng-for`

Comment: Is it possible the top answer on this post is just outdated then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755801/angular-ng-if-inside-option-element-and-ng-repeat-not-working

Comment: no it's not, it says that you can't insert html element (or tag, it's the same) inside an `<option>` element, but I'm only using attributes here: And he's using attributes too

Comment: Oh i see now! My mistake haha

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ng-selected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected).
For example:

```
 <option ng-selected="valueCheckingIfThisObjectHasBeenPreviouslySubmitted">{{myObject.thisOption}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on MarcoS' answer and Naigels suggestion to use `ng-repeat`, I think I've solved it like so:

```
<select
id="someId"
class="someClass"
ng-class="someMethodToGetDynamicClass('this')
ng-model="myObject.thisOption"
ng-disabled="valueCheckingIfThisObjectHasBeenPreviouslySubmitted">
<option ng-repeat="item in [{'k':true, 'v':'Yes'}, {'k':false, 'v':'No'}] ng-selected="valueCheckingIfThisObjectHasBeenPreviouslySubmitted && item.k == myObject.thisOption" >{{item.v}}</option>
```

The `ng-repeat` now repeats across an array of objects storing my value to be checked on ('k'), and a display label ('v'). `ng-selected` then checks if `valueCheckingIfThisObjectHasBeenPreviouslySubmitted` is trueand if the current `item.k` is equal to the submitted value.