# How to do tabulator in HTML dropdown to format text

Tags: php, html, format, dropdown

I have a dropdown menu in my HTML-Code, which is filled with a PHP while-loop.
For example:

```
<select name="dd1" class="form-control" id="dd1">
   <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>Select...</option>
   <?php 
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>"> <?php echo $row['PName'] .  "\t | " . $row['AName'] ?> </option>
   <?php 
     } 
   ?>    
</select>
```

[image]

I want to do a tabulator between the Name1 | Name2. I tried this with \t, but it has been ignored.
Anyone an idea what I can do?

If I do it with & emsp; it looks like this:

[image]

I want that all of the second Names, that means starting by |, have the same postion.

Comment: Just use 4 `&nbsp;` and it should do the trick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a tab character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660987/how-to-get-a-tab-character)

Comment: @JoeBlack no it's not, please read my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to pad your strings with spaces and then replace spaces with `&nbsp;` (provided that you use a monospace font):

```
<select name="dd1" class="form-control" id="dd1">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>Select...</option>
    <?php
    $widthLeft = 30; // width in symbols
    $widthRight = 30; // width in symbols
    $separator = '|';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $optionFormatted = sprintf("%-{$widthLeft}s{$separator}%-{$widthRight}s", $row['PName'], $row['AName']);
        $optionHtml = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $optionFormatted);
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>"> <?php echo $optionHtml ?> </option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>    
</select>
```

More solutions:

- [Can I use HTML tags in the options for select elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements)
- [How can I style a select option like a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879753/how-can-i-style-a-select-option-like-a-table)

---

**Update:**

For multibyte strings you may use the following function:

```
<?php
function mb_strpad(string $input, int $pad_length, string $pad_string = ' ', int $pad_type = STR_PAD_RIGHT, string $encoding = 'UTF-8'): string
{
    $diff = $pad_length - mb_strlen($input, $encoding);

    if ($diff <= 0) {
        return $input;
    }

    $pad = str_pad('', $diff, $pad_string);

    if ($pad_type === STR_PAD_LEFT) {
        return $pad . $input;
    }

    return $input . $pad;
}
```

So that your code will look like this:

```
<select name="dd1" class="form-control" id="dd1">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>Select...</option>
    <?php
    $widthLeft = 30; // width in symbols
    $widthRight = 30; // width in symbols
    $separator = '|';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $optionFormatted = mb_strpad($row['PName'], $widthLeft)
                . $separator
                . mb_strpad($row['AName'], $widthRight);
        $optionHtml = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $optionFormatted);
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>"> <?php echo $optionHtml ?> </option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you that works partially. if there are umlaute like ä ü ö or ß its not correct anymore

Comment: @Alex Please, check the update to my answer, concerning the multibyte strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `&emsp;` instead of `\t` then see your output

```
<select name="dd1" class="form-control" id="dd1">
   <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>Select...</option>
   <?php 
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>"> <?php echo $row['PName'] .  "&emsp; | " . $row['AName'] ?> </option>
   <?php 
     } 
   ?>    
</select>
```

Comment: but they are not all the same length, so they get diffrent potisions of the names 
I edit my post, so you can see what I mean