# MySql CONCAT columns with fixed width

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `members` where I fetch values by concatenating `FName` and `LName` (as `Full_Name`) columns.

Here is my query: `select CONCAT(FName,' ',LName) as Full_Name from members`

The result will be like this

```
Full_Name
XXXXX XXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX
XXX XXXXXXXXXX
```

Is there any way to fetch data with a Fixed Width ? I tried with `CAST` function, but it won't aligns the results

```
Full_Name
XXXXX          XXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX
XXX            XXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: The way you're displaying values should affect the way you fetch data in any way. Fix it where you display it, not in the query. That being said, it'd probably be better if you fetch the data separately and put it together in the view.

Comment: Is there any special reason you want to put it in the database this way?

Comment: @Michel It is not for adding data, but only to show in a `select` box in HTML. If it can be formatted like my requirement in PHP, then also it is OK

Comment: @El_Vanja If it can be formatted like my requirement in PHP, then also it is OK

Comment: Even if you fill with blanks, you have to use a monospaced font to align them propperly. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25879753/1685196)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a query. You have to find the longest `FName` and then `RPAD` to that lenght:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT( RPAD(FName, alen + 5," " ), Lname ) AS Full_Name 
FROM(
  SELECT m.Fname, m.Lname, q.alen FROM members m
    JOIN(
    SELECT MAX(LENGTH(Fname)) AS alen FROM members
    ) q
) m
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/650c12e/2)

Comment: what is flen here ? It will be an undefine column.

Comment: @Typo, tested it in my own db with different names

Comment: Its not working as according to the OP requirement. There are some spaces issues in it.\

Comment: @JohnDoe Does `CONCAT` remove extra spaces? When I use a dot it works prefect (see fiddle), with spaces not.

Comment: @Michel It works with a dot. But blank space or `&nbsp` not working. I will continue with a dot (or any other character) for time being. Thanks anyway

Comment: Its working with dot but not with spaces man.

Comment: @user3045457 Weird, in my own db (Server version: 10.1.29-MariaDB)  it works like a charm with spaces too.

Comment: @Michel in my phpMyAdmin, Space works fine. But I put the result in `select` box in html file, spaces disappears. :) You know the reason :) So I end-up with a dot for time being

Comment: @user3045457 I got it working using `CHAR(0xc2a0)`  (= UTF-8 non breaking space) instead of `" "`.  Still needs a monospaced font to align propperly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the representation login should be done in code. So I post below PHP code solution:

```
<?php
// Find the longest name
$query = "SELECT MAX(LENGTH(FName)) as max_name from members;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$max_name_length = $stmt->fetchColumn();

// Fetch table data
$query = "SELECT FName, LName from members;";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$members = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Build data representation
foreach($members as $member) {
    echo str_pad($member['FName'], $max_name_length + 2) . $member['LName'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Execute PHP code online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=325ac5f686736be3fcca77017a7eed6c&sqlses=25ad39c6f46d567c6334a62d31949ed2&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score -1):

Use the right padding function with the first name and then concat them.

Comment: Pad to what lenght? You first have to know what is the longest Fname

Comment: @Michel use the max(select len(Full_name) from members)

Comment: This can be a comment instead of an answer. How someone can add right padding without knowing the length of FNames in the database.

Comment: @JohnDoe getting the length aint a big issue.

Comment: Add some code for reference atleast. The way you write can be a comment only/

Comment: @JohnDoe sure will take care next time. thanks

Comment: @OmkarArora Assuming and hardcoding a max length of Fname, your solution works fine. Note: double spaces in `select` box html not works