# dropdown selected option text issue( css not working )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know how to solve this issue, I am trying create fixed width span inside the option in dropdown, though it looks cool when I open dropdown, but when I select any option, spaces are removed

[**JSFiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/w79tufp4/)

When I open dropdown I can see,

```
  100px each span
  <- 100px   -> 
  | id        |Instrument    |X           |Y          |Date          |
```

But when I select any option from dropdown it looks like below, without any space or gap between span

```
   idIstrumentXYDate
```

**Please someone help me to solve the issue, or any alternate method to get same effect**

**HTML**

```
<select id='profile_dropdown'></select>
```

**CSS**

```
.dp_opts {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px !important;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    text-align:left !important;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var spanit = function () {
    var h = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        h += "<span class='dp_opts'>" + arguments[i] + "</span>";
    }

    return h;
}

var opt, dropdown = document.getElementById("profile_dropdown");


opt = document.createElement("option");
opt.innerHTML = spanit("id", "Instrument", "X", "Y", "Date");
opt.value = 'none';
dropdown.options.add(opt)

for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.innerHTML = spanit(i, i + 1, i + 2, i + 3, i + 4);
    opt.value = i;
    dropdown.options.add(opt)
}
```

Comment: you could just add some tabs or whitespaces: `opt.innerHTML = spanit(i + "\t", i + 1 + "\t", i + 2 + "\t", i + 3 + "\t", i + 4 + "\t");`

Comment: Check this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements

Comment: @m02ph3u5 : but I need fixed width

Comment: you can't do that... you need to look at some other solution like customized dropdowns

Comment: @ArunPJohny : can you please provide me alternate solution ? I need to get same effect

Comment: do you use libraries like jQuery

Comment: @ArunPJohny : Yes Sir, I use jQuery, but I could not get same effect, once after selection its shows texts without space

Comment: have a look at plugins like http://jquery-plugins.net/select-js-styleable-select-elements