# False value of boolean object evaluates to true

Tags: javascript

Why javascript Boolean object with false value evaluates to true.

```
var bln = new Boolean(false);
if (bln) {
    alert('true');
} else {
    alert('false');

}
```

Comment: Because every object evaluates to `true`.

Comment: This is a really good example of why *you should debug with the console*. Logging `bln` to the console would have solved this mystery.

Comment: You can use primitive values (`false` instead of `new Boolean(false)`) or use the `valueOf` function: `new Boolean(false).valueOf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `new Boolean(false)`(`typeof new Boolean()` == `'object'`) returns an object, not a primitive value, objects are by default truthy in nature

Comment: can you please provide me alternate solution for the same here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013512/dropdown-selected-option-text-issue-css-not-working