# How to use a template in a select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I'm able to create a pseudo-select list in Knockout.js by doing this:

```html
<div style="width:325px;height:500px;overflow:auto;" data-bind="template: { name: 'group-tmpl', foreach: explorer().categoryData }"></div>
```

But you don't get the styling and selected value as you do with a `<select>`.

I tried to do this, but got an error saying you can't use a template in this data-bind.

```html
<select data-bind="options: explorer().categories, value: explorer().selectedCategory, optionsText:'name', template: 'group-tmpl'" size="15" />
```

I also tried to specify a template in the `<option>`, but that didn't render correctly (just saw a list of `[object Object]`).

One of the things I wanted to have was an image in the `<option>`. So I guess I could try to use css & after the load use jQuery to set the attr, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using Knockout.

I'm hoping that I missed something obvious and/or easy.

Comment: [You can't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements) have images or other HTML in native `<option>` elements. You will need to mimic select behavior with your first code example, and eventually encapsulate it in a custom binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters pointed out you can't have much fancy stuff inside `option`s and `select`s in general. You'll need to use a library like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/), [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), or [Selectize](https://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/), backed by a normal `select`, typically.

To answer your concrete question though, if you want to use a templated `foreach` inside a select you can perfectly well do so:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  items: [
    { txt: "option A" },
    { txt: "option B" },
    { txt: "option C" }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="itemTmpl">
<option>~~~<!-- ko text: txt --><!-- /ko -->~~~</option>
</script>
<select data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTmpl', foreach: items }"></select>
```

Again, you can't *do* anything fancy inside the `script` template, because you can't do anything fancy inside a `select` to begin with. But it *is* possible to use a template + `foreach` on a select. One typical use case where this is useful is when you want (custom) `optgroup`s. Another use could be that you want to include special attributes (aria- attributes perhaps?) on the `option`s.