# Customize html output for a field's droplist options

Tags: html, css, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a field called icon, which is a droplist sourced from folder in the content tree. I would like the list to not just show the text value(shown in the screen shot) but also to utilize an icon font and display what the actual icon would look like. Basically customizing the content editor's droplist for this field from:

```
<option value="gears">gears</option>
```

to

```
<option value="gears">gears <span class="my-icon-font-gears"></span></option>
```

Is there any documentation on how to modify the outputted html for a droplist, and to modify the content editor page to load another link, in this case a font-file.

[image]

Comment: You would need to create a custom field inheriting from droplist as well as [load your custom css stylesheet](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/adding-custom-javascript-and-stylesheets-in-the-content-editor/) into the Content Editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you use the `Droplink` field type instead of the Droplist, since the value is stored by `GUID` and this will lead to less longer term problems if the link item is renamed or moved. In any case you need a custom field, inherit from `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.LookupEx` (which is the DropLink field type) and override the `DoRender()` method with the custom markup you require.

It's not possible to embed a `span` tag since the [option tag cannot contain other tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements) as it is invalid HTML. Adding it will cause the browser to strip it out. You can however set the class on the option itself and style that.

```
`<option value="gears" style="my-icon-font-gears">gears</option>`
```

Here is some sample code to achieve the field.

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Globalization;

namespace MyProject.CMS.Custom.Controls
{
    public class StyledLookupEx : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.LookupEx
    {
        private string _styleClassField;
        private string StyleClassField
        {
            get
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_styleClassField))
                    _styleClassField = StringUtil.ExtractParameter("StyleClassField", this.Source).Trim();
                return _styleClassField;
            }
        }

        // This method is copied pasted from the base class apart from thhe single lined marked below
        protected override void DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(output, "output");
            Item[] items = this.GetItems(Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(this.ItemID, Language.Parse(this.ItemLanguage)));
            output.Write("<select" + this.GetControlAttributes() + ">");
            output.Write("<option value=\"\"></option>");
            bool flag1 = false;
            foreach (Item obj in items)
            {
                string itemHeader = this.GetItemHeader(obj);
                bool flag2 = this.IsSelected(obj);
                if (flag2)
                    flag1 = true;
                /* Option markup modified with class added */
                output.Write("<option value=\"" + this.GetItemValue(obj) + "\"" + (flag2 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : string.Empty) + " class=\"" + obj[StyleClassField] + "\" >" + itemHeader + "</option>");
            }
            bool flag3 = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Value) && !flag1;
            if (flag3)
            {
                output.Write("<optgroup label=\"" + Translate.Text("Value not in the selection list.") + "\">");
                output.Write("<option value=\"" + this.Value + "\" selected=\"selected\">" + this.Value + "</option>");
                output.Write("</optgroup>");
            }
            output.Write("</select>");
            if (!flag3)
                return;
            output.Write("<div style=\"color:#999999;padding:2px 0px 0px 0px\">{0}</div>", Translate.Text("The field contains a value that is not in the selection list."));
        }
    }
}
```

This field adds a custom properties to allow you to specify the linked field to use for the style class. The assumption is that you have another single line text field on the linked item to specify the CSS class.

Usage: Set the source property of the field in the following format:

```
Datasource={path-or-guid-to-options}&StyleClassField={fieldname}
```

e.g. *Datasource=/sitecore/content/lookup/iconfonts&StyleClassField=IconClassName*

To use this new field compile the above code in to project, switch over to the core database and then create a new field type – you can duplicate the existing Droplink field located in `/sitecore/system/Field types/Link Types/Droplink`. Delete the existing Control field and instead set the ASSEMBLY and CLASS fields to point to your implementation.

You also need to load a custom CSS stylesheet with the style defintions into the Content Editor, which you can achieve that by [following this blog post](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/adding-custom-javascript-and-stylesheets-in-the-content-editor/).

Answer (score 2):

I created a module on the marketplace that does something similar. You can have a look [here](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/I/Icon_Selector_Field.aspx?sc_lang=en). There is some documentation on there explaining how to use it.

[image: Icon Selector]

[image: Icon Selected]

The code is also on Git if you want to have a [look](https://github.com/Wesley-Lomax/icon-selector-field).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on your module. I'll try to utilize your code as a starting point.