# HTML tags inside Angular interpolation

Tags: angularjs

I have created a select box using ng-repeat. Inside `option` tag I am showing two values using Angular interpolation directive, and I want to show second text at right. I am trying to use HTML inside `{{}}`. But it is not working.

```
<select class="large" name="selectlarge" id="selectlarge" ng-model="selaccount">
<option value="{{cloneditem.description}}" selected="selected" ng-repeat="cloneditem in stub.custServDetails.cloningItems">
<p>
{{cloneditem.description}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{<p style="float:right">cloneditem.balance</p>}}
</option>
</p>
</option>
</select>
```

Comment: First, you have some errors in your tag. You can't insert html inside option tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements

Comment: @Alexis : Right, but is there any way to do it.

Comment: Maybe with a library who custom the select element.

Answer (score -1):

I think this

```
{{<p style="float:right">cloneditem.balance</p>}}
```

needs to be

```
<p style="float:right">{{cloneditem.balance}}</p>
```

(The HTML needs to be outside the curly brackets).

Comment: I am using it inside option tag, and we cannot write html tags inside option tag

Comment: Oh sorry, I must have overlooked that part. To the best of my knowledge, however, it's not possible to have HTML inside Angular expressions.