# How make to make dropdown without html select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used the following html to make a dropdown:

```
<div class="container">
<select id="search-pax" name="pax" class="ls-select ">
  <p>Start the selection</p>
  <option value="1">1 gas <span>1700</span></option>
  <option value="2">2 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="3">3 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="4">4 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="5">5 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="6">6 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="7">7 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="8">8 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="9">9 gaste</option>

  <option value="10">10 gaste</option>              
  <option value="11">11 gaste</option>              
  <option value="12">12 gaste</option>              
  <option value="13">13 gaste</option>              
  <option value="14">14 gaste</option>              
  <option value="15">15 gaste</option>              
  <option value="16">16 gaste</option>              
  <option value="17">17 gaste</option>              
  <option value="18">18 gaste</option>              
  <option value="19">19 gaste</option>              
  <option value="20">20 gaste</option>              
  </select> 
</div>
```

So, as you can see [here in the html and the running snippet](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/gWYNVe), I tried to add paragraph tag inside the select tag, tried styling the option and nothing works.

The objective is to achieve something like the photo, where I select an item,the item would go to the input field.

Hope you can help.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use HTML tags in the options for select elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **USE `<ul>` `<li>`**

Hi,

If you want add any `HTML` tags inside your item list. Best way is use `<ul>` `<li>` with combination of `css` and some `Jquery` tricks to display as Dropdown

Try below sample code

```js
$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.toggle();
});
// Check this click evnet - 
$("body").on("click", "#ddlDemoDropdown li", function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).attr('data-value')
    alert(selectedValue)
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:30px;
}
ul { 
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
ul li { padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 2; }
ul li:not(.init) { float: left; width: 130px; display: none; background: #ddd; }
ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) { background: #09f; }
li.init { cursor: pointer; }

a#submit { z-index: 1; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='ddlDemoDropdown' class="list-unstyled" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="init" data-value="-1">--SELECT--</li>
    
    <li data-value="value 1">Option 1</li>
    <li data-value="value 2">Here you can add any HTML tags like <input style='width:30px;' type='text' /> Textbox ... ;) </li>
    <li data-value="value 3">Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

### **EDIT:-**

Check below `click` event and I also updated my snippet .. you can check now

```
$("body").on("click", "#ddlDemoDropdown li", function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).attr('data-value')
        alert(selectedValue)
    });
```

Comment: I just edited the snippet according to my requirements and it works.
http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/gWYNVe
Appreciate the support

Comment: @WosleyAlarico - Glad to help you ... :-) .. as we can see in <li> tag we can add any HTML tags we want ....

Comment: Absolutely. I am trying to understand the jquery you added. I know it is not part of the question part I hope you do not mind explaining or editing it in a a way that I can get the value of a any li  tag I choose.  Guess you would you .val() but am just struggling to make it work. and display using the console.log.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico - I understand your requirement ... I updated my code snippet ... you can check again now ....

Comment: Just found the way and added as the final answer for this topic. Appreciate again the support

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use optgroup to set your desired element/header. `<p>` is not a valid element under `<select>`.

```
<div class="container">
<select id="search-pax" name="pax" class="ls-select ">
<optgroup label="Start the selection">
  <option value="1">1 gas <span>1700</span></option>
  <option value="2">2 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="3">3 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="4">4 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="5">5 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="6">6 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="7">7 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="8">8 gaste</option>                    
  <option value="9">9 gaste</option>

  <option value="10">10 gaste</option>              
  <option value="11">11 gaste</option>              
  <option value="12">12 gaste</option>              
  <option value="13">13 gaste</option>              
  <option value="14">14 gaste</option>              
  <option value="15">15 gaste</option>              
  <option value="16">16 gaste</option>              
  <option value="17">17 gaste</option>              
  <option value="18">18 gaste</option>              
  <option value="19">19 gaste</option>              
  <option value="20">20 gaste</option> 
</optgroup>            
  </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: The answer help. But am still not able to style the option tag. There are span tags inside and I would like to move the numbers to the right and obviously just as the picture I posted, I should be able to give some padding to the DropDowns.

Comment: What you see in the picture there is not a select dropdown. Thats a custom made list made from other none form elements (except the search field). You need to change your approach if you need full customization possibilities. Check out https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for a dropdown with the `ul` and `li` from the html code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#input").click(function(){
    $("#selectives").css('display', 'block');
    $("input").css('borderRadius', '2px 2px 0px 0px');
  });


  $(".auswahl").click(function(){
    var das = $(this).html();
    $("#input").val(das);
    $("#selectives").css('display', 'none');
    $("input").css('borderRadius', '2px');
  });

});
```

```css
p {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
body {height: 510px; font-family: Arial}
#selectives {height: 10px; position: absolute; top: 32px; left: -32px; display: none;}
#input {position: relative; }
input:hover {cursor: pointer; }
input::-moz-selection {background: white; color: #000}
input {width: 107px; border-radius: 2px; border: 0.1em solid black; -webkit-appearance: none; padding: 5px; font-size: 10px;}
ul {margin-top: 0px;list-style-type: none; text-align: left;}
li {width: 107px; border-color: black black orange black; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; padding: 5px; border-radius: 0px; font-size: 10px; border-top: 0px;}
li:last-child {border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px; border: 1px solid black; border-top: 0px;}
li:first-child {border-radius: 0px; border-bottom: 1px solid orange; border-top: 0px;}
li:hover {background-color: ghostwhite; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly id="input" type="text" value="Dropdown">
<div id="selectives">
  <ul>
    <li class="auswahl">Hello</li>
    <li class="auswahl">This</li>
    <li class="auswahl">Is</li>
    <li class="auswahl">An</li>
    <li class="auswahl">Example</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a textbox and a div that you will make visible on click. Inside the div you will have tabular data. It's how many of the ui date inputs are made. Or try to use a framework like jquery, bootstrap, etc ...

This does need a bit of css styling though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using select box use select2.

Please follow the examples and code here:

https://select2.github.io/examples.html

This will help to achieve you want.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use and customise this plugin. this plugin will help to give searching functionality and many more features. 
**how it works** 
behind the seen there will be a  select html and plugin will convert this into the custom html which you can further modify and implement styles according to your taste 
https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer I achieved the desired as you seen in following snippet:

```
http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/gWYNVe?editors=1111
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled" style="list-style: none;">
    <li class="init">--SELECT--</li>
    <li data-value="value 2"><span class="value">Durban</span><span class="numbers">1700</span></li>
    <li data-value="value 3"><span class="value">Durban</span><span class="numbers">1400</span></li>
    <li data-value="value 4"><span class="value">Durban</span><span class="numbers">1200</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  padding:30px;
}
ul { 
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
ul li { padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 2; }
ul li:not(.init) { float: left; width: 130px; display: none; background: #ddd; }
ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) { background: #09f; }
li.init { cursor: pointer; }

a#submit { z-index: 1; }

li{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}
li, ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.toggle();

    console.log($('.selected .value').text());
});
```