# Dropdown menu of multiple pages on one html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I want to put  multiple distinct pages into one html page.  I have the code for this already, but now I want to put the pages into a dropdown menu.  For example with the code I provided, I want 1 to be the only item displayed and then if you click on it there is a drop down menu with 2 and 3.  And then once 2 is selected it is the only item displayed, but once you click it there is a drop down menu with the rest of the items.  I've played around with the code, but I don't know how to put them into this dropdown menu.  Does anyone have any solutions?

EDIT: I would prefer to form the drop down menu without using a select box. 
 I would like to customize the drop down box to make it look cleaner and apart of the page, and you cant do this with a select box. I would like things such as the text centered, and when you the options drop down they drop down in a white box with no border/outline.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H4dbJ/)

```js
function show(elementID) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(elementID);
    if (!ele) {
        alert("no such element");
        return;
    }
    var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
    for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        pages[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    ele.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
span {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>Show page <span onclick="show('Page1');">1</span>, <span onclick="show('Page2');">2</span>, <span onclick="show('Page3');">3</span>.
</p>

<div id="Page1" class="page" style="">
    Content of page 1
</div>
<div id="Page2" class="page" style="display:none">
    Content of page 2
</div>
<div id="Page3" class="page" style="display:none">
    Content of page 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with **jquery**, using the on [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event:

```js
$("#drop").on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value) {
    $(".page").hide();
    $("#Page" + value).show();
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropStyle {
  width: 100px;
  /*text-indent: 35px;*/
  padding-left: 6%;
  background-color: white;
  /*border:none*/
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Show page
<select id="drop" class="dropStyle">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="Page1" class="page" style="">
  Content of page 1
</div>
<div id="Page2" class="page" style="display:none">
  Content of page 2
</div>
<div id="Page3" class="page" style="display:none">
  Content of page 3
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anyway I could do this without a select box?  I would like to customize the drop down menu to make it look cleaner and apart of the page.  I want to make changes such as centering the text, and having the dropdown background be white with no borders.

Comment: @user7548188 You can do it using <ul><li> tag's, take a look in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362588/how-make-to-make-dropdown-without-html-select/43362673), I also edited the answer by adding a new style.