# HTML main category dropdown selection and sub-category list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have seen other questions asked where `select` and `optgroup` were given, but where more CSS styling is needed, is there a way to show the sub-categories from a menu created using `radio inputs`?

The snippet shows the menu animation that is required so `select` won't work here. I changed the HTML markup to `radio inputs`. Is it possible to toggle the associated sub-category div when the main-category is select?

```js
$(".cat-dropdown .title :input").click(function() {
  var $menu = $(this)
    .parent()
    .siblings(".cat-dropdown-menu");
  if ($menu.height() > 0) {
    closeMenu($menu);
  } else {
    openMenu($menu);
  }
});
$(".cat-dropdown-menu .cat-item").click(function() {
  var $menu = $(this).closest(".cat-dropdown-menu");
  closeMenu($menu);
  $menu
    .closest(".cat-dropdown")
    .find(".title span")
    .text($(this).text())
    .css("color", this.style.color);
});

function closeMenu($menu) {
  $list = $menu.children(".cat-list");
  $menu.closest(".cat-dropdown").toggleClass("closed");
  $menu.css("height", 0);
  $list.css("top", 0);
}

function openMenu($menu) {
  $list = $menu.children(".cat-list");
  $menu.closest(".cat-dropdown").toggleClass("closed");
  $menu.css({
    height: 75
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cat-list input {
  display: none;
}

.sub-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main1 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.main2 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.cat-dropdown {
  margin: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #343c3f;
  border: 1px solid #a2acb0;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .cat-dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .cat-dropdown-menu .cat-item {
  height: 0px;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .title {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.cat-dropdown.closed .title:after {
  margin-top: -16px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.cat-dropdown .title {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e1e4;
}

.cat-dropdown .title:after {
  display: block;
  content: "▾";
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  margin-top: -16px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: "border-box";
  -moz-box-sizing: "border-box";
  box-sizing: "border-box";
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list .cat-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d9e1e4;
  padding: 0 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  transition: margin-top 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

.cat-dropdown .cat-list .cat-item:hover {
  background-color: #d9e1e4;
  color: #343c3f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-dropdown closed">
  <div class="edit">
    <label class="title">
<input class="edit-input1" type="checkbox"><span> Choose...</span>
</label>
    <div class="cat-dropdown-menu">
      <div class="cat-list" id="category">
        <label class="cat-item" style="color:blue">
<input type="radio" name="cat1">Main 1</label>
        <label class="cat-item" style="color:red">
<input type="radio" name="cat2">Main 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
Sub Category:
<div id="subcategory">
  <div class="sub-list main1" for="cat1">
    <input type="radio" name="sub1" value="opt1">main1 opt1
    <input type="radio" name="sub1" value="opt2">main1 opt2
    <input type="radio" name="sub1" value="opt3">main1 opt3
  </div>
  <div class="sub-list main2" for="cat2">
    <input type="radio" name="sub2" value="opt1">main2 opt1
    <input type="radio" name="sub2" value="opt2">main2 opt2
    <input type="radio" name="sub2" value="opt3">main1 opt3
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/LmLZeM

Comment: Instead of putting whole code here better you would have uploaded it to codepen or something similar, so that people can test

Comment: Great idea Harsh. I updated the post with a codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to toggle the associated sub-category div when the
>   main-category is select?

Yes, and this what worked for me:

```
function toggleSubcatDiv( input ) {
  var name = $( input ).attr( 'name' );

  $( '.sub-list[for="' + name + '"]' )
    .siblings( '.sub-list' )
      .filter( '.active' )
        .removeClass( 'active' )
      .end()
    .end().addClass( 'active' );
}
```

Where I used the `function` in this closure:

```
$(".cat-dropdown-menu .cat-item").click(function() {
  var $menu = $(this).closest(".cat-dropdown-menu");
  closeMenu($menu);
  // ... your code here.

  toggleSubcatDiv( $( ':radio', this ) ); // <- here's where I used that function
});
```

Then I added this custom `CSS`:

```
.sub-list:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
```

So `toggleSubcatDiv()` will either add or remove `active` from the `class` attribute of the sub-category `div` (i.e. `.sub-list`).

See demo on https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NMyKvp (PS: I did not change the `HTML` markup; however, you could pre-select the *Main 1* `div` by adding `active` to the `class` of that `div`.)

**UPDATE**

In reply to your comment, this should work so long as the sub-category `div`s are placed in (or added to) the same `.container` `div`:

```
function toggleSubcatDiv( input ) {
  var name = $( input ).attr( 'name' );

  $( '.sub-list[for="' + name + '"]' )
    .closest( '.container' )
      .find( '.sub-list.active' )
        .removeClass( 'active' )
      .end()
    .end().addClass( 'active' );
}
```

So what changed is, that we now find the closest parent/container which is shared by the sub-category `div`s.

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmQoRg

Comment: Thanks Sally. Your solution works great. I'm having trouble at site level however because in my markup I have to have the `sub-list` in dynamic wrappers so they are no longer `siblings` and now they compile instead of radio. https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/vjdVZq

Comment: Working. It would be great to be able to select one of the inputs under an instance of `for="catx"` to show initially. Could we add a `data-attribute` to one of the `sub-list input` with the name of the specific sub-category we want to select?

Comment: Actually that feature already exists. =) Just add `active` to the `class` of the `.sub-list` `div`. See the updated [Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmQoRg). And secondly, you should use `$( '.sub-list[for="' + name + '"]', '.container' )` (i.e. provide a context) so that we're only 'activating' the `.sub-div` in `.container`. Or you can try this version: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NMyVYb (see the notes at the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 1):

I once had to do something similar, this was what I came up with:

```
<script>
  function subselect(cat){
    var select = "";
    if (cat == 1) {
      select = "<select><option value='a1'>a1</ooption><option value='a2'>a2</ooption></select>"
    }else if (cat == 2) {
      select = "<select><option value='b1'>b1</ooption><option value='b2'>b2</ooption></select>"
    }
   document.getElementById("subcategory").innerHTML = select;
  }

</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-dropdown closed">
  <div class="edit">
    <label class="title">
<input class="edit-input1" type="checkbox"><span> Choose...</span>
</label>
    <div class="cat-dropdown-menu">
      <div class="cat-list" id="category">
        <label class="cat-item" style="color:blue">
<input type="radio" name="cat" onclick='subselect(1)'>Main 1</label>
        <label class="cat-item" style="color:red">
<input type="radio" name="cat" onclick='subselect(2)'>Main 2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
Sub Category:
<div id="subcategory">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style media="screen">
          select optgroup{
            display: none;
          }
          input.a:checked + input + select optgroup[label=a]{
            display: block !important;
          }
          
          input.b:checked + select optgroup[label=b]{
            display: block !important;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        a<input class="a" type="checkbox" name="sel" value="a">
        b<input class="b" type="checkbox" name="sel" value="b">
        <select class="" name="">
          <optgroup label="a">
            <option value="a1">a1</option>
            <option value="a2">a2</option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="b">
            <option value="b1">b1</option>
            <option value="b2">b2</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This is an example of how you could alter a list using the `:checked` psuedo selector. When using psuedo selectors you need to be able to navigate to the element you want to alter. Our `input.a` has to traverse to its second sibling, but `input.b` only has to travers to its first.

Comment: Thanks Thomas but in order to keep the styling I can't use `select` for the menu options. I am wondering if this type of selection can be done without using `select`

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to overwrite the styling of the `select` element?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362588/how-make-to-make-dropdown-without-html-select/43362718

Comment: Was basing my assumption from the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select

Comment: That answer is mostly referring to Window's ie. Look at this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: I see. So how do we recreate the snippet using the inputs as structured in the question? The animation of the original menu needs to stay the same