# Inserting elements to appended elements using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fairly new to JS, and have created a little piece of script and it does exactly what I want which is find some  elements then adds  elements with data populated from via ajax....
So I go from this...

```
<select><select/>
```

to this...

```
<select>
  <option value="{ajax value data}"> {ajax text data} <option/>
  ...
<select/>
```

using this piece of script...

```
filteredSelectIds.forEach(function (item) {
    let itemId = '#' + item;
    let itemData = item.split('-')[0] + 's';
    $.each(data[itemData], function (i, color) {
      $(itemId).append($('<option/>', {
        value: color.optionValue,
        text : color.optionText
      }));
    });
  });
```

Now, what I am trying to do is at the same time add a Font Awesome icon to each  element so I need to end up with something like this,,,,

```
<select>
  <option value="{ajax value data}"><i class="fa fa-icon"> {ajax text data} <i/><option/>
  ...
<select/>
```

How would I do that??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use HTML tags in the options for select elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new at JS, try this.

```
element = '<i class="fa fa-icon"> {0} <i/>'.format("{ajax text data}")
$('<option/>').append( element  );
```

Comment: Someone @brk did reply with a solution..... But for some reason when I came back to look at it, it was deleted and replaced with a comment from  Tibrogargan? Fortunately I manged to get the solution, and it did work! However, after reading the link that Tibrogargan posted, I realized that putting the <i><i> element inside the <option><option/> would not work as elements cannot be placed inside them! So I will post both that solution as it shows how to insert an element inside another,,, And my solution which I used...

Answer (score 0):

So @brk gave me this solution which worked, and would work for putting an Element inside another

"Create the option tag & i tag & first append itag to option tag and then append option tag to item"

```
filteredSelectIds.forEach(function (item) {
        let itemId = '#' + item;
        let itemData = item.split('-')[0] + 's';
             $.each(data[itemData], function (i, color) {
var selOption = $('<option value="' + color.optionValue + '"></option>');
               selOption.append('<i class="fa fa-icon">'+color.optionText+'<i/>');
               $(itemId).append(selOption); }); });
```

However, although this placed the  element inside the  element as I wanted, and this could principle could probably be used to place any element within another, Tibrogargan correctly pointed to a question that makes the point that elements cannot be place within  elements (Not really the Point of my question, but helpful). My solution was simply using the unicode for the Font Awesome icon and escaping it with \u then used \xa0 for additional spaces as follows:-

```
filteredSelectIds.forEach(function (item) {
let itemId = '#' + item;
let itemData = item.split('-')[0] + 's';
$.each(data[itemData], function (i, color) {
  $(itemId).append($('<option/>', {
    value: color.optionValue,
    text : '\ue905  \xa0\xa0\xa0' +color.optionText
  }));
});
```

});

Thanks!