# React Bootstrap - How to render components within FormControl attributes and option tags?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

In general, React Bootstrap allows me to use various types of `FormControls` as so:

```
// Input field 
<FormControl
    type="text"
    placeholder="Placeholder text"
    value={this.props.value}
    inputRef={(ref) => this.inputfield = ref}
/>

// Dropdown menu
<FormControl componentClass="select"
    defaultValue={this.props.someId}
    inputRef={(ref) => this.dropdownmenu = ref}
>
    <option key='firstoption' value={0}>Select Options</option>
    {this.props.options.map((o) =>
        <option key={o.id} value={o.id}>{o.description}</option>
    )}
</FormControl>
```

However, now say I want to add a "tag" inside the text field and on certain options of the dropdown menu.

I've included a picture to show you what I mean. 
[image]

I want a blue box showing the name of a certain tag within the input field and if anyone types in it, they type to the right of the tag, not underneath it or over it.

In the same vein, I want the tag to appear in a dropdown menu (shown in the expanded view and how it will be when selected).

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

The only thing I've tried is this:

```
import React from 'react';

export class TagComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <span className="somecss">Some Tag</span>
        );
    }
}

-------------------------
// Input field 
<FormControl
    type="text"
    placeholder={this.props.ifTagExists && <TagComponent /> && "Placeholder Text"}
    value={this.props.ifTagExists && <TagComponent /> && this.props.value}
    inputRef={(ref) => this.inputfield = ref}
/>

// Dropdown menu
<FormControl componentClass="select"
    defaultValue={this.props.someId}
    inputRef={(ref) => this.dropdownmenu = ref}
>
    <option key='firstoption' value={0}>Select Options</option>
    {this.props.options.map((o) =>
        <option key={o.id} value={o.id}>{o.ifTagExists && <TagComponent />} {o.description}</option>
    )}
</FormControl>
```

Tried that and it did not render the tag component. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

see a similar question,

> you cannot use tags within the `option`tag.

[Can I use HTML tags in the options for select elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements)

Also you cannot do anything of that you are doing for `placeholder` or `value`.
Checkout the html reference!

also checkout the `selectize` library, it might help you getting what you want. if you want to implement something like that yourself, it is also a good start where you can checkout the source code.

http://furqanzafar.github.io/react-selectize/#/