# Any simple HTML5 / CSS3 method for hiding selected option text?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML select menu that shows options for different currencies in both abbreviated and long format. E.g.

```
<select>
    <option selected>USD <span>(United States Dollar)</span></option>
    <option>GBP <span>(Great British Pound)</span></option>
    <option>AUD <span>(Australian Dollar)</span></option>
</select>
```

Is there any way I can hide the long format text inside the `span` for the selected option without relying on a library like Select2? E.g.

[image: Example output]

I tried simply using this, but it did nothing:

```
option:checked span {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So if you just want to hide the text in the currently selected option (when the dropdown is not 'expanded') then you can just set the width of the element.

```css
select{
  max-width:4em;
  font-family:monospace;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option selected>USD (United States Dollar)</option>
    <option>GBP (Great British Pound)</option>
    <option>AUD (Australian Dollar)</option>
</select>
```

This will only work if the prefix that you want to show is always the same width. So that is why I have set a monospace font. You will also need to make sure your value prefix is always a fixed number of characters. If you wanted to use a different font or variable text you would have to do something cleverer to ensure consistent widths.

If you want to change the dropdown itself, then you will need to modify the values or use some kind of custom dropdown. Some examples:

- https://codepen.io/sverrirs/pen/dXJLRa
- https://freefrontend.com/css-select-boxes/
- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp

Comment: This feels a bit dirty but I don't want to use a library for something so trivial so this will be the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: I understand - tricks like this can be convenient at times but I would honestly suggest using some kind of widget kit for any substantial project. A single widget like a dropdown can be surprisingly tricky, and the tools we get with pure HTML aren't really good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't put html tags inside a option on a select:
See: [Can I use HTML tags in the options for select elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements)
Your spans are removed on the tree:

```
<select>
    <option selected="">USD (United States Dollar)</option>
    <option>GBP (Great British Pound)</option>
    <option>AUD (Australian Dollar)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is also an option.

**HTML Example:**

```
<select id="people" class="people">
    <option value="0">John</option>
    <option value="1">Peter</option>
    <option value="2">Greg</option>
    <option value="3">Nate</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.people').find('option:contains('Peter')').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible with only css maybe with width spectrum. u can use bootstrap and bootstrap select framework.

You can see it here :
https://jsfiddle.net/uniak/nmfo45e8/

```css
div.test {
display: flex;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="test">
    <select class="selectpicker">
      <option selected title="USD">USD (United States Dollar)</option>
      <option title="GBP">GBP (Great British Pound)</option>
      <option title="AUD">AUD (Australian Dollar)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And Look at example from here: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/