# React.js: problem with passing variable from select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In GetTariffs.js file, I get the tariff values from the GET-request.
In the AddForm.js file there is a POST-request for sending data. There was a problem with the transfer of values from the GET-request (drop-down list) from GetTariffs.js file to AddForm.js file.

The values in the drop-down list are not displayed on the page:
[image: The values in the drop-down list are not displayed on the page]
But in the source code values are present:
[image: But in the source code values are present]

GetTariffs.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class GetTariffs extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tariffs: [],
            isLoaded: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/v1/tariff/all')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    tariffs: json,
                })
            })
    }

    render() {

        var {isLoaded, tariffs} = this.state;

        if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>loading</div>
        }

        else {
            return (

                <div>
                    {tariffs.map(tariff => {
                        return <option name="tariff" key={tariff.id} value={tariff.name}>
                            {tariff.name}
                        </option>
                    })}
                </div>

            )
        }
    }
}

export default GetTariffs
```

AddForm.js:

```
...
import GetTariffs from "./GetTariffs";
...
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
...
                    <div className="form-container">
                        <h5>Тариф</h5>
                        <div className="form-row">
                            <div className="form-group col-md-12">
                                <select id="inputState" className="form-control" onChange={this.changeGetTariffHandler}>
                                    <GetTariffs/>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Use a `Fragment` instead of a `div` for wrapping your options so that it will get stripped out. a `div` is not a valid child of `select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because the options are bounded by `div`.
You want the options to be the children of the `select` tag.

Try bound the options with `React.Fragment` instead of bounding the options in div. React Fragment exists exactly for situations like these :)

[React Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

The render should look something like that:

```
render() {

    var {isLoaded, tariffs} = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
        return <div>loading</div>
    }

    else {
        return (

            <React.Fragment>
                {tariffs.map(tariff => {
                    return <option name="tariff" key={tariff.id} value={tariff.name}>
                        {tariff.name}
                    </option>
                })}
            </React.Fragment>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `<option>` cannot have children: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements

Comment: @ZhanwenChen in this case `option` doesn't have a children.

Answer (score 1):

Они не отображаются, потому что ты обернул их в div.
They don’t appear because you wrapped them in div.

Use:

```
 <>
   <option></option>
   <option></option>
 </>
```