# How to put table tag inside a option tag of select tag in HTML?

Tags: html

I have a select tag in HTML, I want to put table tag inside one of the option tag. I don't know whether it is possible or not. If not possible then suggest alternate way to solve this problem. Here I'm attaching my HTML code:

```
<select name="abc" style='width:850px;'><option>Student Roll No.:<%=gsrn.getSrollno() %></option> 
<option>
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr bgcolor="#00004d">
<th>Serial No</th>
<th>Total Marks</th>
<th>Percentage</th>
<th>Aggregate</th>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#0059b3" style="text-shadow:3px 3px 3px #000000">
<td>1</td>
<td><%=gsrn.getTmarks1() %></td>
<td><%=gsrn.getPer1() %></td>
<td><%=gsrn.getAgg1() %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td><%=gsrn.getTmarks2() %></td>
<td><%=gsrn.getPer2() %></td>
<td><%=gsrn.getAgg2() %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td><%=gsrn.getTmarks3() %></td>
<td><%=gsrn.getPer3() %></td>
<td><%=gsrn.getAgg3() %></td>
</tr>
</table>
</font>
</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can't do this. `<option>` tags cannot contain any other tags. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements

Comment: However you can create a custom select box. For example, take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/ZTHkQ/850/ (you will have to integrate the table support yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change select for radio type and use tables, or use a css to simulate a table.