# Is it possible to append icons and buttons to dropdown/form-select?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a dropdown using Vue and Bootstrap, which should display a number of options and a delete button attached to each option. I can't seem to append any html to the options. I am using the form-select component as I would like to bind a selected option with a v-model. My code currently looks something like this...

```
<b-input-group>
      <b-form-select
        v-model="options"
        size="sm"
        @change="onSelectedOptionChanged"
      >
        <b-form-select-option :value="null"
          >-- Saved options--
        </b-form-select-option>

        <b-form-select-option
          v-for="(set, index) in optionSet"
          :value="set"
          :key="index"
          >{{ set.name }}

        </b-form-select-option>

      </b-form-select>
      <!-- <b-input-group-append>
        <b-button title="Delete" @click="deleteOptionSet" class="btn-sm"
        ></b-button>
      </b-input-group-append> -->
    </b-input-group>
```

Is this possible and if so, how can I approach this? I've already tried using prepend-html and simply inserting html. Thanks

EDIT: It looks like it's not possible to add html tags inside a select tag. I'd really like an alternative resolution, however. Is this functionality possible with a dropdown instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use HTML tags in the options for select elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements)

Comment: @Hiws It certainly explains why I can't use HTML in a select tag, but I'd like to know if this is possible in a dropdown also.

Comment: Since you are using Bootstrap, I suggest replacing the dropdown (same thing as select BTW) with a [Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) containing your list with buttons.

Comment: @Tim B-dropdown is not the same thing as form select, is it?

Comment: I resolved my issue by switching the b-form-select for b-dropdown to allow HTML in each option/item like so: `<b-dropdown-item
            v-for="(set, index) in filterSets"
            :value="set"
            :key="index"
            @click="setSelectedFilterSet(set)"`

Comment: Nice to know that @Mr_Happy is happy once again.