# Iterator .map return [object object] when I have a tag inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this array:

```
[
    {
      label: "Linkedin",
      social_handle: "linked_in",
      handle: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/",
      content: "",
    },
    {
      label: "Twitter",
      social_handle: "twitter",
      input_handle: "https://twitter.com/",
      input_content: "",
    },
    {
      label: "Website",
      social_handle: "website",
      input_handle: "",
      input_content: "",
    }]
```

And I iterate him in the next code:

```
<select
   onChange={(e) => props.handle(e)}
   className="form-control"
>
  {props.socials_arr.map(({ label, social_handle }) => (
  <option key={social_handle} defaultValue={social_handle}>
    <i class="fas fa-linkedin"></i> {label}
  </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

But this return me this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqhyH.jpg)

How I can solve the [object object] and have the icon there?

Comment: You can't with `<option>`. It only supports text as content. You might want to try to create a your own dropdown menu.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements

Comment: Oh, ok, roger that.